# Is User Psychology similar to the use of empathy?

Tags: users, psychology, experience

So I've been doing some read up about UX hoping to firm up my base as a UX practitioner and was just wondering and thinking if User Psychology is similar to the use of empathy.

Understanding that a good UX Designer understands their User well, so in terms of designing, both of these (Empathy and generally Psychology) are aspects that contributes too.

Answer (score 1):

Empathy and general psychology are two different approaches, that help you to understand users goals, constraints, reasoning, feelings etc. But they have a lot of overlapping and they also complement each other.

I see empathy as more a skill acquired with practice, whereas general psychology is more about theories and general findings about human behavior.